# Prove that a function is Riemann integrable directly, using $\epsilon-P$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I know there already  are questions like these, but I still don't understand how to prove it.

Question:

> Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ if
>   $$f(x) =  \begin{cases} x^2 \sin (1/x) & \text{if  } 0 < x \le 1 \\ 0 &\text{if }x = 0.\end{cases}$$

Do I use an epsilon proof or do I use the method of showing that 
$$\sup L(P, f) = \inf U(P,f)$$

I read that both are equivalent and my teacher prefers the second method, but I really want to understand both. Also, my teacher doesn't use epsilon-delta proofs, just epsilon by proving: $$\sup L(P, f) - \inf U(P,f) < \epsilon $$

**Remark** I know that the function is continuous, and being continuous, it is integrable. But I want to prove the integrability directly.

Comment: Could you tell us what you are trying to prove, first? Give a specific example, don't ask for how to solve a class of questions without giving us at least examples.

Comment: What are "questions like these"? Questions like *what*? You haven't really asked even one.

Comment: You really need to include more details. Also, generally, pick _one_ questio to ask per post. Lists are not well-received.

Comment: Show that $f$ is continuous $[0,1]$. Then it's integrable (general fact: A continuous function is integrable)

Comment: Showing that it'continuous isn't enough. My teacher demands a mathamatical proof.

Comment: Then also show your teacher all continuous functions are integrable. I am sure this can be found in your textbook.

Comment: I know that's true and so does my teacher, but this is one of the topics on an upcoming test. The goal is to be able to give these kind of proves, not to do it the easy way.

Comment: I've edited your question, so that it kind of reflect what you really want to ask. Feel like to rollback.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a "direct" proof we have to use the precise definition of $f$ somehow. Compute
$$f'(x)=2x\sin{1\over x}+x^2\left(-{1\over x^2}\right)\>\cos{1\over x}\qquad(0<x\leq1)\ .$$
It follows that
$$|f'(x)|\leq3\qquad(0<x\leq1)\ .$$
Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given.  Partition $[0,1]$ into subintervals $J_k$ $(1\leq k\leq N)$ of width $\leq{\epsilon\over  3}$. Since $f$ is continuous on each of the closed intervals $J_k$ it follows by the MVT that $$\sup_{x\in J_k} f(x)-\inf_{x\in J_k} f(x)\leq 3 \>{\epsilon\over 3}=\epsilon\qquad(1\leq k\leq N)\ .$$  For this partition ${\cal P}$ we have
$$U({\cal P},f)-L({\cal P},f)\leq\sum_{k=1}^N\epsilon |J_k|\leq \epsilon\ .$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary we can conclude that
$$\inf_{\cal P}\bigl(U({\cal P},f)-L({\cal P},f)\bigr)=0\ ;$$
therefore $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.